# Apache rewrite url : remove text between last backslash(including) and last dot

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to convert links like :

http://domain.com/images/67/ajjk3jj/7fdbf3a6a338ae5032ec2d1f08a2670f_81acc0dfd24507aa74b1de52767edca7/image.jpg

in links like :
http://domain.com/images/67/ajjk3jj/7fdbf3a6a338ae5032ec2d1f08a2670f_81acc0dfd24507aa74b1de52767edca7.jpg

So actualy i want to remove the text "/image" from the original link.
"image" text varies

I did something like but doesn't work. I need it only to show original file name in the images links but to store them in files generated names.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)\/(?!.*\/)(.*?)\.(?!.*\.)(.*?)/$ /$1.$3 [L]
```

Tested the regular expresion with php preg_replace and it works,but i get 404 error with apache.

i want to put the htaccess file in the root of the uploads folder.

If I manually remove the text from the link it leads to good image, so the only problem is the htaccess code.

**LATER EDIT:** 
if i make something like this works so is not a problem with modrewrite module :

```
RewriteRule ^images/67/ajjk3jj/7fdbf3a6a338ae5032ec2d1f08a2670f_81acc0dfd24507aa74b1de52767edca7/image.jpg$ images/67/ajjk3jj/7fdbf3a6a338ae5032ec2d1f08a2670f_81acc0dfd24507aa74b1de52767edca7.jpg
```

jpg extension is not fixed, can be any kind of image

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/[^/.]+(\.jpg)/$ /$1$2 [L,NC,R]
```